# How to find all newest record for one type?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
id type value date
1  A    10    2018-08-01
2  A    20    2018-08-02
3  A    30    2018-08-04
4  B    11    2018-08-01
5  B    12    2018-08-02
6  C    11    2018-08-01
```

I would like get one latest record for one type:

```
id type value date
3  A    30    2018-08-04
5  B    12    2018-08-02
6  C    11    2018-08-01
```

How can I write this sql?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You could use the query above as a sub-query to get the max date for each type and join against the table by the date.

Comment: @gacopu The accepted answer doesn't satisfy the brief. So either the accepted answer is wrong, or the question is wrong. To demonstrate, swap around the 'values' of type B

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use  `max()`function and subquery

```
select t.* from tableA t inner join

   ( select type ,max(value) as value, max(date) as d_date from tableA

    group by type ) as t1 on t.date =t1.d_date and t.type=t1.type
```

Comment: hello downvoter may i know the reason of downvote??

Comment: See your previous downvoted answers.

Comment: @Strawberry sir in their you  said that was not my fault that was op's fault

Comment: See the manual, which provides several correct patterns for this kind of query.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ties with `date`, then you can use `limit` clause with `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id = (select t1.id
            from table t1
            where t1.type = t.type
            order by t1.date desc
            limit 1
           );
```